# Instancing the Application class in Unit Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, retrofit, android-testing

I am attempting to write Unit Tests on an Android project, but have run into a roadblock with creating an instance of the Application class. The project uses Retrofit and LiveData with Android Architecture Components.

Currently, I am trying to test my **AuthRepository** 's **login** function, but I can't create an instance of the repository because it is dependent on a custom **SharedPrefs** class which is dependent on a **Application** class.

**AuthRepository**

```
@Singleton
class AuthRepository @Inject constructor(
    val retrofitService: RetrofitService,
    val sessionData: SharedPrefs
) {

    fun login(username: String, password: String): LiveData<LoginResponse> {

        return getCSRF().then {
            if (it.result is GenericResponse.ErrorType) {
                // Error Accepting Terms
                val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<LoginResponse>()
                mutableLiveData.value = LoginResponse(listOf(LoginResponse.ErrorType.Generic()))
                mutableLiveData
            }
            else {
                retrofitService.postLogin(LoginBody(username, password))
                    .map {
                        val res = LoginRemote.parseResponse(it.response)
                        return res
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SharedPrefs**

```
class SharedPrefs @Inject constructor(context: Application) {

    private val sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.company.project.domain.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    private val PREF_KEY_SESSION_COOKIE = "sessionCookie"

    // SharedPreference Variable Management
    var sessionCookie: String
    get() = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_KEY_SESSION_COOKIE, "")
    set(value) = saveString(PREF_KEY_SESSION_COOKIE, value)

}
```

With this set up this way, is it possible for me to run plain old UnitTests for my AuthRepository? Or is the dependency on **Application** going to force me to use Instrumentation Tests in order to test my AuthRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can mock `Application` class using Mockito:

```
@Mock private lateinit var context: Application

@Before fun setupTasksViewModel() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}
```

2. or mock `SharedPrefs` object

   ```
   @Mock private lateinit var prefs: SharedPrefs
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Since you have been able to answer a lot of my questions, would you mind if we started a private chat? Now that I have that, I need to figure out how to `observe` the response  which requires an instance of **LifeCycleOwner**

Comment: sure, lets figure out that together

Comment: Great, what's the best way to open a chat?

Comment: I thought you know :)

Comment: I was going to contact you through your linked in profile, but it's not valid?

Comment: I added my Linkedin link to my profile. Would you mind sending me a message via LinkedIn?

Comment: sure, I've sent request

Comment: Okay, I've opened a chat. Talk to you there